# JPA try to delete if fails set inactive

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i have the following entity A (imagine B as just a simple enitity with an active/inactive-flag which can be referenced by other entities)

```
@Entity
public class A { 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private B b;
}
```

i need to try to remove b, but if it is referenced by other entities i want to fall back to inactivating it.

imagine something like this

```
public void removeB() {
    B toRemove = this.b;
    this.b = null;
    try {
        entityManager.remove(toRemove);
        entityManager.flush();
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        toRemove.setActive(false)
    }
}
```

the problem is that this gives me the error

```
Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

Any idea how i can achive this?

**EDIT**

my problem is not about showing error messages to the user, for that i found library that could do that

https://blog.42.nl/articles/recovering-from-database-constraint-violations-in-java/

my problem is about recovering from any exception that might occur in a delete

Comment: javax.persistence.RollbackException means that something got broken and it just hides real cause. Try to turn on more detailed logging to see real exception that is behind this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach (just idea, details depend on JPA provider):

```
public void deleteB(B b) {
   Long count = entityManager.createQuery("select count(a) from A a where a.b.id = :b")
                             .setParameter("b", b.getId())
                             .getSingleResult):
   if (count == 0L) {
       // delete B
   } else {
       // make B inactive
   }
}
```

Handling your specific case:

In your example you have a RollbackException, which indicates that persistent context syncronization operation (most likely it is ***flush*** in your example) failed and marked a whole transaction for rollback.

You have no good ways to handle it after it happened. However, you can try to predict it before your transaction will fail. For example, try to delete B in another transaction to check if deletion will fail. This is a dirty trick, but seems to be the only way for your database api design.

Comment: that would be an option but i have many more tables referencing that entity, some of them are not even mapped in hibernate. one could reformulate the problem as, is there a way to recover from a failed delete in JPA.

Comment: @cproinger it depends on the situation. Do you delete B as a single object in transaction or you have another modified objects in same context?

Comment: i have another modified object in the same context

Comment: @predict: so i could delete it in another transaction which i rollback myself if it works so i am able to delete it in my transaction. excellent suggestion. i like it

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you must persist whole model change. You changed this.b to null but this was not stored into database, only B is being deleted. I would expect some constraint issue in A - B relation. Try to persist A with this.b = null **before** B removal.

Comment: thats a valid point, i should maybe flush after this.b = null and again after the remove but my question is more about how i can recover from a failed delete without the transaction beeing marked as rollback.